# WPF: Treeview Item Root uses different template then child nodes

Tags: wpf, templates, binding, treeview

I currently am trying to bind my business object to a treeview as the root. And its collection property as the child. [I want to achieve this via BINDING]

Something like this.

```
public object MyBusinessObject
{
   private int _number;
   private bool _isSelected;
   private ObservableCollection<AnotherObject> _other = new ObservableCollection<AnotherObject>();


   public int Number { get {return _number;} set {_number = value;}}
   public bool IsSelected{ get {return _isSelected;} set {_isSelected= value;}}
   public ObservableCollection<AnotherObject>  Children { get {return _other;}}

}
```

I want my treeview to be represented like this:

- "CheckBox binded to IsSelected" "Text binded to Number"

  - List of child binded to my "Children"
  - List of child binded to my "Children"
  - List of child binded to my "Children"
- "CheckBox binded to IsSelected" "Text binded to Number"

  - List of child binded to my "Children"
  - List of child binded to my "Children"
  - List of child binded to my "Children"

I have no idea how to do this in xaml:

```
  <TreeView x:Name="_tv" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyBusinessObject}" >

            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate> 
                    <CheckBox Content="{Binding Path=Number} IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>
        </TreeView>
```

I know the above is not right, but i was wondering if there is a way to do this properly.

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure, you can use the HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate property to define the data template to be used for the collection of AnotherObject instances.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollectionOfObjects}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">

            <!-- This is used for your AnotherObject instances -->
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>

            <!-- This is used for your MyBusinessObject instances -->
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Number}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />

        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: WOW, thanks a lot, I thought it didn't work, but end up i had a typo when i copyed your code on my object name. Thanks A LOT MAN

Comment: For others who are reading this, be sure to add ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyBusinessObject}" to the TreeView element in order to make this work.

Comment: Well the OP used that in his example but it doesn't necessarily convey the fact that the ItemsSource actually needs to be a collection of objects. Binding it directly to a single MyBusinessObject will not work. If there's only one root item it still needs to be in a collection of one.

Comment: I added an ItemsSource attribute to make the example clearer.